# logEvents on Facebook with Ionic 2

Tags: facebook, angular, ionic2, facebook-javascript-sdk, cordova-plugins

I want to track some events in Facebook from my Ionic 2 app, but I don't undertand how to do it.

I'm using [this plugin to login with Facebook](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/facebook/).

And if you see the available methods, there is a `logEvent(name, params, valueToSum)`

But what does it expect for each attribute?
In name, is any name or one predefined of the event to be tracked?
Which params should It contain?
ValueToSum?

Does anyone have an example, please?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Since it explicitly links to the documentation for app events in iOS and Android, it presumably uses the same values you would use with the native SDKs …

Comment: Yes, but for example, I don't know if I should send a string on the "name" parameter or what. Because in the Facebook docs for Android it does something like: `logger.logEvent(AppEventsConstants.EVENT_NAME_ADDED_TO_CART, 54.23, parameters);`

But in my app, if I write: `Facebook.`  facebook doesn't contain an AppEventsConstants or Event names

Comment: Well then pass the event name directly ...